# Windows Phone 7 Silverlight Dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, grid

I am trying to form a dynamic grid, in which the user determines number of rows and number of columns, also I am trying to use a Panorama control as a parent for the grid. In addition, I want the grid to have one control in each cell.

Is all of this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but not recommended.

Reasons this could be bad:

- Building grids dynamically can take time and the performance hit may be noticable.
- The phone form factor doesn't support large grids well (due to the relatively small amount of available real estate) so there may be a better way of displaying the content you wish to.
- You could end up with a large grid inside a Panorama control. In turn this could lead to a large panorama which again may have performance implications.

Comment: Thanks, and I figured out all of that, so now I have shifted the project into another direction.
Nevertheless, I have stumbled upon another problem which is the TextBox being not scrollable.
is there any way out?.